# Carriage return in print() for Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Why is the carriage print function not compatible with python 2.x when I import the `print_function` from `__future__`?

I can do this in python 3:

```
import time
for i in range(5):
    print('Loop %d' % i, end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
```

And I was hoping this would work the same way in python 2 but it does not.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
for i in range(5):
    print('Loop %d' % i, end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Any ideas?

P.S. I know that `sys.stdout.flush` is an alternate solution to this problem.

Comment: What do you mean that it "does not work"?  What do you expect it to do?  What does it do instead?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @BrenBarn my intention was for people to copy-and-paste my code and run it themselves. The Python 2 version prints "Loop 4" only after the loop has completed for me.

Comment: Perhaps it's my python 2 anaconda environment that is giving me problems, since it works for you @TigerhawkT3